# ¿Como saber si el ha recibido una notificación en iOS?

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

Cuando los usuario reciben una notificación necesito que en la base de datos Firebase quede reflejado el "recibido". Cuando el teléfono está con la pantalla encendida funciona pero cuando no está encendida no funciona. Pero sin embargo si que se ejecuta el código donde hago referencia para que dé "recibido" en la bd. esto lo sé por que en la consola de Xcode se ejecutan los print de prueba del appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        print("Estoy en 5")
    }
    print(userInfo)
    print("Estoy en 6")

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)


    guard
        let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")]as? NSDictionary,
        let id = aps["idMensaje"] as? String

        else{

            return
    }

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = user?.uid
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("mensajes").child(id).child(uid!).child("recibido").setValue("ok")

        print("da recibido 6")



        let nav = UINavigationController()

        let principal:ViewControllerNotificacion = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcNotificaciones") as! ViewControllerNotificacion
        principal.idMensaje = id
        nav.viewControllers = [principal]
        self.window!.rootViewController = nav
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        print("Estoy en prueba1")




    }
```